# SQL Server - Queries to check Memory Settings

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

May I know how to check the below current settings in the SQL Server from one of the Databases(Queries)

1. In-memory OLTP storage (GB)
2. Target IOPS (64 KB)
3. Number of replicas

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best set of Dynamic Management View queries was created by [Glenn Berry](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/sql-server-diagnostic-information-queries-for-january-2018/). Naturally, DMVs vary based on edition of SQL Server. Thus, you'll have to run the right query for your 2008 and 2012 versions, respectively.

Storage:

```
SELECT physical_memory_in_use_kb/1024 AS [SQL Server Memory Usage (MB)],
       locked_page_allocations_kb/1024 AS [SQL Server Locked Pages Allocation (MB)],
       large_page_allocations_kb/1024 AS [SQL Server Large Pages Allocation (MB)], 
       page_fault_count, memory_utilization_percentage, available_commit_limit_kb, 
       process_physical_memory_low, process_virtual_memory_low
FROM sys.dm_os_process_memory WITH (NOLOCK) OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

All Database properties, including if they are a replica

```
-- Recovery model, log reuse wait description, log file size, log usage size  (Query 31) (Database Properties)
-- and compatibility level for all databases on instance
SELECT db.[name] AS [Database Name], SUSER_SNAME(db.owner_sid) AS [Database Owner], db.recovery_model_desc AS [Recovery Model], 
db.state_desc, db.containment_desc, db.log_reuse_wait_desc AS [Log Reuse Wait Description], 
CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), ls.cntr_value/1024.0) AS [Log Size (MB)], CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), lu.cntr_value/1024.0) AS [Log Used (MB)],
CAST(CAST(lu.cntr_value AS FLOAT) / CAST(ls.cntr_value AS FLOAT)AS DECIMAL(18,2)) * 100 AS [Log Used %], 
db.[compatibility_level] AS [DB Compatibility Level], db.page_verify_option_desc AS [Page Verify Option], 
db.is_auto_create_stats_on, db.is_auto_update_stats_on, db.is_auto_update_stats_async_on, db.is_parameterization_forced, 
db.snapshot_isolation_state_desc, db.is_read_committed_snapshot_on, db.is_auto_close_on, db.is_auto_shrink_on, 
db.target_recovery_time_in_seconds, db.is_cdc_enabled, db.is_published, db.group_database_id, db.replica_id,
db.is_encrypted, de.encryption_state, de.percent_complete, de.key_algorithm, de.key_length
FROM sys.databases AS db WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN sys.dm_os_performance_counters AS lu WITH (NOLOCK)
ON db.name = lu.instance_name
INNER JOIN sys.dm_os_performance_counters AS ls WITH (NOLOCK)
ON db.name = ls.instance_name
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_database_encryption_keys AS de WITH (NOLOCK)
ON db.database_id = de.database_id
WHERE lu.counter_name LIKE N'Log File(s) Used Size (KB)%' 
AND ls.counter_name LIKE N'Log File(s) Size (KB)%'
AND ls.cntr_value > 0 
ORDER BY db.[name] OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

I/O

```
-- Get I/O utilization by database (Query 35) (IO Usage By Database)
WITH Aggregate_IO_Statistics
AS (SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) AS [Database Name],
    CAST(SUM(num_of_bytes_read + num_of_bytes_written) / 1048576 AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) AS [ioTotalMB],
    CAST(SUM(num_of_bytes_read ) / 1048576 AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) AS [ioReadMB],
    CAST(SUM(num_of_bytes_written) / 1048576 AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) AS [ioWriteMB]
    FROM sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(NULL, NULL) AS [DM_IO_STATS]
    GROUP BY database_id)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ioTotalMB DESC) AS [I/O Rank],
        [Database Name], ioTotalMB AS [Total I/O (MB)],
        CAST(ioTotalMB / SUM(ioTotalMB) OVER () * 100.0 AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS [Total I/O %],
        ioReadMB AS [Read I/O (MB)], 
        CAST(ioReadMB / SUM(ioReadMB) OVER () * 100.0 AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS [Read I/O %],
        ioWriteMB AS [Write I/O (MB)], 
        CAST(ioWriteMB / SUM(ioWriteMB) OVER () * 100.0 AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS [Write I/O %]
FROM Aggregate_IO_Statistics
ORDER BY [I/O Rank] OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

If you want to get even more fancy, and really see things about your server with some warnings about things that could be wrong, then I'd use [Brent Ozar's sp_Blitz](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/). It's heavily documented there, so just give it a run and drool over the results.

Comment: How do I say my SQL Server has this much of In-memory OLTP storage (GB) like they say in the [link] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-vcore-resource-limits-single-databases. Same question for Target IOPS too.

Answer (score 0):

For In-Memory OLTP, I wrote a script to evaluate memory-optimized instances and databases, called sp_BlitzInMemoryOLTP, which is part of Brent Ozar's First Responder Kit.

https://www.brentozar.com/thanks/welcome-sql-server-medical-school/

Documentation here: http://nedotter.com/archive/2018/06/new-kid-on-the-block-sp_blitzinmemoryoltp/